# python: use a increasing variable to repalce

Tags: python

i write a small script as follow

```
f1 = open('file.txt', 'r')     
f2 = open('newfile.txt', 'w')     
n=5000

for line in f1:         
      f2.write(line.replace('12345', n))    
      n=n+1

f1.close()     
f2.close()
```

but `.replace('old','new')` can not apply to a variable. any people hav idea to solve this?

Comment: You should show your error messages. Actually, first you should **read and attempt to understand** your error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to give two strings to replace:

```
f2.write(line.replace('12345', str(n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `n` to a string when replacing with it:

```
f2.write(line.replace('12345', str(n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you are trying to replace a string with a number.

Change your line to this:

```
f2.write(line.replace('12345',str(n)))
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

use str(n) to change n into a string

```
f2.write(line.replace('12345', str(n)))
```